# ElasticSearch not running on localhost:9200 after apt-get install

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch from Ubuntu repositories using

```
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

After that I assumed the service would be setup and running, but when I opened `localhost:9200` it was not running. Is there additional configuration or command that I need to run?

*Edit*: I also ran `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service` (ubuntu is on systemd) but no effect.

Comment: What does your log file in `/var/log/elasticsearch` tell you?

Comment: more suitable for serverfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a clean ubuntu 16 (in vagrant) I have success starting elastic search doing the next steps:

```
apt install elasticsearch
```

uncomment in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` the line

```
START_DAEMON=true
```

And this is the important one:

```
systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

Note that `start` won't work because elasticsearch comes disabled by default but systemd consider it started (it is something like "started in disabled state") so after change the defaults file you must restart the service

more info on: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730

Answer (score 5):

Elasticsearch is not started automatically after installation. You need to enable elasticsearch explicitely, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/deb.html

Comment: I ran `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service` (ubuntu is on systemd), but elasticsearch still wasn't running on 9200.

Comment: then use the systemd tools to find out whats happening. `journalctl` allows you to check the output. In addition check the elasticsearch log file

Answer (score 3):

Run `systemctl status elasticsearch` if you're not getting any logs in `/var/log/elasticsearch`. You can scroll through this output via `f` (for forward) and `b` (for backward) as necessary.

It's possible that you don't have enough memory (RAM) available.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch takes some time to fully come up, here are some of the things you may want to check:

Check the limits in [/etc/security/limits.conf](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/setting-system-settings.html#limits.conf)

```
elasticsearch - nofile 65536
```

Also check for this on `/etc/pam.d/su`

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

If using systemd check in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service`

```
[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

Also, add this:

```
LimitNOFILE=131070
```

Now check the memory in `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` this is something that depends on your system you will have to fine tune if using ansible I use this:

```
-Xms{{ (ansible_memtotal_mb * 0.0007) | int }}g                                                                                                                                                                         
-Xmx{{ (ansible_memtotal_mb * 0.0007) | int }}g
```

but for starting you could just use half of your system, if you have 16GB, give 8:

```
-Xms8g
-Xmx8g
```

Last but not least be aware of the resources that elk stack may need:

> A machine with 64 GB of RAM is the ideal sweet spot, but 32 GB and 16 GB machines are also common.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html#_memory